# SQLite returns only first row through SELECT * Statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am saving some records in my `sqlite` table and records are being saved absolutely fine. Problem comes when I try to retrieve those records. Let's say I have 3 records in my sqlite so when I retrieve those records, it returns me the first record 3 times. Count is correct but why it returns me only first record 3 times?

This is how I am retrieving the records:

```
public ArrayList<Cursor> getAllBookings() {
        ArrayList<Cursor> bookingsList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + BOOKING_TABLE, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            bookingsList.add(cursor);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        return bookingsList;
    }
```

**Please note that I have checked the `table` in `Mozilla SQLiteManager` and all records are successfully stored.**

Comment: I guess you do not understand what a Cursor is. The Cursor contains **all** the rows returned by the query. In the for loop you are adding to the list the same cursor again and again.

Comment: @forpas you can see that after I add the cursor in the bookingsList, I move the cursor to next by calling cursor.moveToNext();

Comment: You move the cursor's index to the next row but you don't retrieve that next row. You just add the cursor to the list again and again. I suggest you read/watch some tutorials in the net to understand how you work with cursors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the cursor itself to your booking list when you should extract and add the values that each cursor row contains.

So if you have a class Booking the method should be declared as

```
public List<Booking> getAllBookings() {
```

Also I think it is better to have a do/while loop here and run it until `cursor.moveToNext` returns false and inside the loop extract all values using `getString` or similar methods

```
List<Booking> bookingsList = new ArrayList<>();
//...
do {
    Booking booking = new Booking();
    booking.setSomething(cursor.getString("somethingColumn"));
    //... other columns
    bookingsList.add(booking);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

If you don't have a custom class then you could use an array or a List for each row.